# Calling functions with click handlers in ExtJS 4

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4

I have a function inside a toolbar, let's call it:

```
Ext.define('MyArchive.Toolbar', { 
  search: function() {
    console.log('searching');
  }
}
```

Now I'd like to call this function when clicking a button.  So I'm adding some click handlers in the afterRender on the toolbar setup:

```
afterRender: function() {
  Ext.getCmp('search-button').on('click', this.search);
}
```

However, this doesn't work and I ultimately need to go the full route of:

```
afterRender: function() {
  Ext.getCmp('search-button').on('click', function() {
    quick_search();
  )};
}
```

Any particular reason why my first attempt doesn't apply the click handler as I expect?

Thanks for any explanations or refactorings!  Additional patterns/idioms welcome...

Comment: We'd need to see some more code. For example, where exactly do you call `xt.getCmp('search-button').on...`? BTW: `Ext.getCmp()` while deceptively easy, is not the best way to get hold of objects. Relyingo n it too much makes changes more difficult.

Comment: I added a commend to the question.  What would be the best alternative to Ext.getCmp() for finding components to access the attributes I need?  Any patterns or idioms out there I should be following?

Comment: Can you please remove the extra dort? ^^ Ext.getCmp('search-button').on.( becomes Ext.getCmp('search-button').on(

Comment: Sorry, typos have been fixed...

Comment: jsfiddle.net might help as a way to display the code directly, in this case.  Assuming it supports ExtJS.

Comment: @mwilliams: See this vidcast: http://tdg-i.com/392/ext-js-screencast-the-dangers-of-ext-getcmp It's ased on ExtJS 3, but most of it holds for 4 afaik.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Next try:

```
    var panelOverall = new Ext.form.FormPanel({
    html: 'bla',
    search: function() {
        console.log('searching');
    },
    buttons: [
        {
            text: 'Moo',
            id: 'button1',
            handler: function(){
                //window.destroy();
            }
        }
    ],
    afterRender: function() {
        Ext.getCmp('button1').on('click', this.search);
    } 
});
```

is working for me.. am I missing something?

Comment: That's a fine question, our code looks identical.  We're testing with Jasmine (http://pivotal.github.com/jasmine/) and our spec isn't jiving with the above.  But I'll give it another look over.  Perhaps we need to look at it with some fresh eyes.  But it seemed unless we wrapped the second argument for the click handler was a function - we couldn't get the search function to fire as expected.  I'll follow up with my results...